# Use preg_replace() to replace text on a paragraph

Tags: php

I just found out about the function `preg_replace()` in PHP but I don't know how to fully use it yet. I have texts on my site that I need to get updated and I think `preg_replace()` can do the job.

I need to replace similar texts:

```
@kev need to replace the @ symbol at the end of this paragraph, @example...
```

To:

```
@kev need to replace the @ symbol at the end of this paragraph, example...
```

Basically:

```
@example...
```

To:

```
example...
```

I have so little time to research about the function further so I really needed to ask. Thanks!

Comment: I 'm not sure if waiting for an answer is a better use of your time than researching. Also, `preg_replace` is not the tool for everything by virtue of you having just discovered it.

Comment: Noted Jon. It's just that I've been coding the whole day and researching about `preg_replace()` to make my code work may take quite some time. I notice that here on SO, sometimes users reply with an answer so quickly.

Comment: Keep in mind that SO answers are good at enhancing and clarifying knowledge, but usually not so good at instilling it (at least IMHO). You can't really expect to get a good handle on anything substantial with just a few paragraphs' worth of answer. If you want to learn `preg_replace`, read about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Otherwise you 'll be here again tomorrow and the day after that.

Comment: @Jon the post is not so bad. It's a little bit tricky because there are `@` in the text as well

Comment: @Jon **I** would confirm what you are saying but this would mean that regex related posts aren't allowed anymore here on SO. you can have a look at the awk or sed tag.. questions there are mostly related to regex problems

Comment: @hek2mgl: IMHO the question is borderline bad (for evidence look no further than the exchanges you have with the OP while attempting to answer it) and perhaps should be closed as "not a real question". But I 'm not bashing anything or anyone. Just saying that I believe the OP has much better (in the long term) options than asking questions when they find themselves in this position. Yes, better options require more time but that's how it is in life.

Comment: @Jon Thx for your reply. While I confirm to what you are saying in general, I'm not confirming in this special case. But that's how it is in life again, sometimes opinions differ. however, cu! :)

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: All points taken. Totally agree with what @Andy said. Apologies I just found myself in a tricky situation (multiple `@` on my paragraph but I only needed to remove the one with `...` on the end) that's why I asked. This situation put me into believing that this community is only open to super hard question then. I don't know, maybe Google can even answer those but not this very specific situation I've encountered. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$str = '@kev need to replace the @ symbol at the end of this paragraph, @example...';
echo preg_replace('~@([\w]*?)\.\.\.~u', '$1...', $str);
```

Output:

```
@kev need to replace the @ symbol at the end of this paragraph, example...
```

Comment: There are `...` on the text that I need to replace sir.

Comment: Not really what I needed sir. Will update my question, it seems vague. Apologies.

Comment: :) btw, note that you can omit the `sir` in conversation here.

Comment: @kevinandrada Ok, finally I understood the problem. Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hardcoded, but working solution:

```
$string = "@kev need to replace the @ symbol at the end of this paragraph, @example..." ;

preg_match_all("/\s+@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $string, $matches) ;
$new = preg_replace("/@{$matches[1][0]}/", "{$matches[1][0]}", $string);

echo $new ;
```